# Cast exception on my custom Adapter

Tags: c#, android, listview, mono, xamarin.android

I'm currently having a issue with the Android ListView in Monodroid.

I initialize and set up the list with a custom adapter like this:

```
ListView setting_listview = new ListView(this);
//Components and layoutparameters is done here

RelativeLayout bottom_view = new RelativeLayout(this);
//Components/layoutparameters is done here
setting_listview.AddFooterView(bottom_view);

TTListAdapter adapter = new TTListAdapter(this, listdata, Resource.Layout.datatable_list_item,secList);
setting_listview.Adapter = adapter;
```

Now when I try to retrieve the Adapter in another piece of code like this:

```
TTListAdapter adapter = (TTListAdapter)setting_listview.Adapter;
```

I get the following exception: `System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from type HeaderViewListAdapter to TTListAdapter`. Apparantly the Adapter property now returns a HeaderViewListAdapter instead of the expected TTListAdapter that was set during initialisation.

If I do not use `AddFooterView` during the initialisation it will return the original `TTListAdapter` that was set during initialisation.

Why does the Adapter property return a `HeaderViewListAdapter` instead of the originally set Adapter after `AddFooterView` has been called and how can I retrieve the original Adapter if this happens?

EDIT: Rephrased part of the question to make it a little clearer

Comment: it didn't work using brackets? ((TTListAdapter)setting_listview).Adapter; just asking;

Comment: No. The problem is that the Adapter property (not the ListView itself) returns a HeaderViewListadapter instead of the expected TTListAdapter if AddFooterView(bottom_view) has been called on the ListView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After experimenting some more with the `HeaderViewListAdapter` I found out that whenever a `ListView` had header or footer views. It automatically wraps the original adapter in a `HeaderViewListAdapter` which will manage those headers and footers. The original Adapter can then be retrieved by calling the `WrappedAdapter` property in the `HeaderViewListAdapter` class.

Example for my case:

```
HeaderViewListAdapter adapter = (HeaderViewListAdapter)this.setting_listview.Adapter;
TTListAdapter origAdapter = (TTListAdapter)adapter.WrappedAdapter;
```